# c# youtube api error

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, youtube, youtube-api

hi i am trying to make an application which can submit a comment to a youtube video. I am using .net framework 4.0.

when i click a button it spits out this error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Google.GData.Client, Version=1.7.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=04a59ca9b0273830' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

the code i am using is as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.Xml;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
using Google.GData.YouTube;
using Google.GData.Extensions.MediaRss;
using Google.YouTube;
```

the rest of the code is

```
string developerKey;
string username;
string password;

developerKey = "mykey";
username = "my username";
password = "my pass";

   YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("youtube app", developerKey, username, password);
            YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

            Uri videoEntryUrl = new Uri("my vid");
            Video video = request.Retrieve<Video>(videoEntryUrl);

            Comment c = new Comment();
            c.Content = "This is my comment from my app";
            request.AddComment(video, c);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an assembly.  You must have had it handy as a reference when compiling your app, but it's not there where you're testing.

So it has nothing to do with your code, but your build and deploy process — i.e.,  shell scripts, NAnt, VS.

A typical YouTube client will have the following DLL's in the same directory as the EXE (or DLL).

```
Google.GData.Client.dll
Google.GData.Extensions.dll
Google.GData.YouTube.dll
```

If not, then they need to be installed in the GAC, or otherwise locatable using .NET's assembly binding configuration.  Probably you want the first option, though.

Comment: the dll files are within the same folder as the .exe file and its still coming up with the error. what is GAC?

Comment: You must have two different versions. Try substituting the ones in the EXE folder with the ones that are present for compilation.